# jQuery get remaining value of class selector partial

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector

I have an element with multiple classes in it. When I click this class I need to get the remaining part of a class partial as a variable.

I know that the first part of the class will always start with "jump_"

example:

```
<span class="jump jump_toThis randomClass">Something</span>

$('#tray').on('click', 'span.jump', function(e){
    var $this     = $(this),
    classList = $this.attr('class');

    console.log(classList);
    // Not sure how to remove *jump_* from *toThis* 
    // along with the other classes

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#tray').on('click', 'span.jump', function (e) {
    var className = this.className,
        jumper = className.match(/\b(jump_.*?)\b/)[1];
    if (jumper) {
        $(this).removeClass(jumper).addClass(jumper.replace(/^jump_/, ''))
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xevRS/)

If you want to keep only `toThis` as the class then

```
$('#tray').on('click', 'span.jump', function (e) {
    var className = this.className,
        jumper = className.match(/\b(jump_.*?)\b/)[1];
    if (jumper) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(jumper.replace(/^jump_/, ''))
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xYX2J/)

Comment: Thank you, this was a creative solution. I wound up modifying it a bit to create the variable I need, but works great. Thanks SO much!